# how to fetch next value in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a `foreach` loop like below code :

```
foreach($coupons as $k=>$c ){

//...
}
```

now, I would like to fetch two values in every loop .

for example :

first loop: `0,1`

second loop: `2,3`

third loop: `4,5`

how can I do ?

Comment: Either use a for loop or chunk your array with `array_chunk()`

Comment: try to use for($i=0;$i<count($coupons); $i+2) {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split array into chunks of size `2`:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($coupons, 2);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    if (2 == sizeof($chunk)) {
        echo $chunk[0] . ',' . $chunk[1];
    } else {
        // if last chunk contains one element
        echo $chunk[0];
    }
}
```

If you want to preserve keys - use third parameter as `true`:

```
 $chunks = array_chunk($coupons, 2, true);
 print_r($chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use for loop like this :

```
$length = count($collection);

for($i = 0; $i < $length ; i+=2)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm making the assumption you are not using PHP 7.

It is possible to do this **however, it is highly, highly discouraged and will likely result in unexpected behavior within the loop**. Writing a standard for-loop as suggested by @Rizier123 would be better.

Assuming you really want to do this, here's how:

Within any loop, PHP keeps an internal pointer to the iterable. You can change this pointer.

```
foreach($coupons as $k=>$c ){
  // $k represents the current element
  next($coupons); // move the internal array pointer by 1 space
  $nextK = current($coupons);
  prev($coupons);
}
```

For more details, [look at the docs for the internal array pointer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

Again, as per the [docs for foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) (emphasis mine):

> **Note:** In PHP 5, when foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the
>   array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a
>   foreach loop. ***As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP
>   5, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.*** In PHP
>   7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

Answer (score 0):

well this'd be 1 way of doing it:

```
$keys=array_keys($coupons);
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);++$i){ 
$current=$coupons[$keys[$i]];
$next=(isset($keys[$i+1])?$coupons[$keys[$i+1]]:NULL);
}
```

now the current value is in $current and the next value is in $next and the current key is in $keys[$i] and the next key is in $keys[$i+1] , and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your array is something like `$a` below:

```
$a = [
    "a"=>1,
    "b"=>2,
    "c"=>3,
    "d"=>4,
    "e"=>5,
    "f"=>6,
    "g"=>7,
    "h"=>8,
    "i"=>9
];

$b = array_chunk($a,2,true);

foreach ($b as $key=>$value) {
    echo implode(',',$value) . '<br>';
}
```

First we split array into chunks (the parameter `true` preserves the keys) and then we do a `foreach` loop. Thanks to the use of `implode()`, you do not need a conditional statement.